# Javascript Uncaught TypeError on one page of website

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I am trying to add a shopping cart to a website I am creating using Javascript. I am trying to use local storage to keep the number of items in the cart displayed when the page is refreshed. I have been using an online tutorial to help with the Javascript for this. It works perfect on my cart.html page but it will not work on my index.html page, I am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined at main.js:29. My code for index.html and my javascript is below. The code for my index.html and cart.html are identical except the cart.html page does not have the `div class="container"` or any of its content. If i comment this div and its content out of the index.html the javascript error goes away. How would the html content cause this error?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <nav>
            <h2>Shop</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li class="cart">
                <a href="./cart.html"
                  ><i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>Cart<span>0</span></a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="product-img">
              <img src="./Images/mushroom-3587888_640.jpg" alt="" />
              <h3>Grain Spawn</h3>
              <h3>€7.00</h3>
              <a class="add-cart cart1" href="#">Add Cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-img">
              <img src="./Images/mushroom-3587888_640.jpg" alt="" />
              <h3>GGrow Bags</h3>
              <h3>€4.00</h3>
              <a class="add-cart cart2" href="#">Add Cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-img">
              <img src="./Images/mushroom-3587888_640.jpg" alt="" />
              <h3>Mushroom Plugs</h3>
              <h3>€10.00</h3>
              <a class="add-cart cart3" href="#">Add Cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-img">
              <img src="./Images/mushroom-3587888_640.jpg" alt="" />
              <h3>Sterilized Substrate</h3>
              <h3>€8.00</h3>
              <a class="add-cart cart4" href="#">Add Cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
    // main.js
    let carts = document.querySelectorAll(".add-cart");
    let products = [
      {
        name: "Grain Spawn",
        tag: "grainspawn",
        price: 7,
        inCart: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Grow Bags",
        tag: "growbags",
        price: 4,
        inCart: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Mushroom Plugs",
        tag: "mushroomplugs",
        price: 10,
        inCart: 0,
      },
      {
        name: "Sterilized Substrate",
        tag: "sterilizedsubstrate",
        price: 8,
        inCart: 0,
      },
    ];
    for (let i = 0; 1 < carts.length; i++) {
      carts[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        cartNumbers();
      });
    }
    
    function onLoadCartNumbers() {
      let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
    
      if (productNumbers) {
        document.querySelector(".cart span").textContent = productNumbers;
      }
    }
    
    function cartNumbers() {
      let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
    
      productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
    
      if (productNumbers) {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
        document.querySelector(".cart span").textContent = productNumbers + 1;
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
        document.querySelector(".cart span").textContent = 1;
      }
    }
    
    onLoadCartNumbers();
```

Comment: put simply, you need to make sure `carts` actually exists and has elements before you throw it into a `for` loop and access its contents.

Comment: @AGE AFAIK [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) always returns a NodeList object, with `.length` set to `0` if there are no matches.

Comment: typo: `for (let i = 0; 1 < carts.length; i++)` needs to use `i < carts.length;`

Comment: To debug similar errors in the future: the error simply says that when `carts[i].addEventListener(...)` is called, `carts[i]` is undefined. This makes the error easy to find.

Comment: @ChrisG Ah perfect, thanks for that,  I read over that so many times but kept missing it.